# How to have an amsart-like subsection style

Tags: sectioning, punctuation, titlesec, amsart

If you use the `amsart` class, then it puts a period after the subsection title, but not if there is no title. For example, if I write

```
\subsection{Title}
Blah1
\subsection{}
Blah2
```

Then `amsart` produces

> 0.1. **Title.** Blah1
>
> 0.2. Blah2

I tried to achieve this in the article class using titlesec package, but so far I can make the period always appear or never appear. So, with the same coding as above, I get either

> 0.1. **Title.** Blah1
>
> 0.2. **.** Blah2

(notice the extra period after 0.2.) or

> 0.1. **Title** Blah1
>
> 0.2. Blah2

Does anyone know how to have the period appear after the subsection title only when there is actually a title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following example I used the [ifmtarg](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifmtarg) package to define a user command, with the help of `\@ifmtarg`, for testing for an empty macro argument (zero or more spaces will be handled); the `explicit` option for titlesec was used to have control over the title using `#1`; the test for emptyness is performed inside `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\titleempty[1]{\@ifmtarg{#1}{}{#1.}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\titleempty{#1}}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Test Section} test text
\subsection{ } test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I never new there was a package like ifmtarg. Good to know!

Answer (score 3):

The following is possible using [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)'s `explicit` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\ignorespaces#1\unskip}%
  \thesubsection\quad\ifdim\wd0>\z@\relax#1.\fi%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title} Blah
\subsection{} Blah
\end{document}
```

`explicit` allows you to use `#1` to place the argument to `\subsection`. However, it also removes easy use of the `*`-variant from the mix. Not sure whether that's a requirement.

The above sets the `\subsection` title in box 0, tests for its width (in order to see whether it's empty or not, and sets the title with a period if its not empty. As such, ending the title with a period will, of course, result in a double period. Here `\@addpunct` would help.

---

Here's another alternative using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {#8}% <search>
  {\setbox0=\hbox{\ignorespaces#8\unskip}\usebox0\ifnum2=#2\ifdim\wd0>\z@.\fi\fi}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title} Blah
\subsection{ } Blah
\end{document}
```

It follows the same approach as above, but directly fixes the ultimate sectioning call. The condition `\ifnum#2=2` refers to the `\subsection` level (level 2). For all other sections, no punctuation is added.

Comment: If, for some reason, one has one or more blank spaces as the argument of `\subsection`, your code won't produce the desired result.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks, I hope I fixed it now.